# how can you manipulate an html page parsed via Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

so i parsed an html page using nokogiri.

i want to wrap  tags around each occurence of links

`.wrap()` doesn't appear to work properly.

```
puts doc.xpath("//a").wrap("<b></b>");
```

returns just plain regular unchanged html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a flaw in the way `wrap` works.  Here is the source:

```
# File lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb, line 212
  def wrap(html, &blk)
    each do |j|
      new_parent = Nokogiri.make(html, &blk)
      j.parent.add_child(new_parent)
      new_parent.add_child(j)
    end
    self
  end
```

As you can see, instead of replacing `j` with `new_parent`, it adds  `new_parent` to the end of `j`'s siblings.  You can do what you want like this:

```
doc.search('//a').each do |j|
  new_parent = Nokogiri::XML::Node.new('b',doc)
  j.replace  new_parent
  new_parent << j
end
```